# Is their Banach space such that its dual is C[a b] - continuous functions on [a b]?

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Space $C(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$ has a Predual?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107706/the-space-c-omega-mathbbr-has-a-predual)

Is their Banach space such that its dual is C[a b] - continuos functions on [a b] ?

--
[EDIT]

Related question is:

[The Space $C(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$ has a Predual?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107706/the-space-c-omega-mathbbr-has-a-predual)

It seems that comment by  Jonas Meyer to this question contains a negative answer to my question. However some extension of comment is welcome - "by the Krein-Milman theorem this implies that  is not a dual space." - not very clear to me.

PS
Surprising how can similar questions come to mind of different people during the same day ?:)

--

Background:

in finite-dimensions: double dual space is isomorphic to itself.
In infinite-dimensions it is not always true. In particular for space of continuous
functions it is not true (as far as I remember). 
(See [Double dual of the space $C[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47544/double-dual-of-the-space-c0-1) ).

Remark: Dual space of continuous functions is quite well understood - it is a space of 
measures with bounded variation. See e.g.
http://regularize.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/dual-spaces-of-continuous-functions/

Comment: It seems to me that Phil Brooker's answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/107716/1438 completely takes care of this question.  To completely understand the answer, you'd need to read the suggested reference (Albiac and Kalton's book)...

Comment: Regarding my comment, that was specific to the real case.  Krein-Milman and Alaoglu imply that the weak*-closed convex set generated by the extreme points of the unit ball of a dual Banach space is equal to the unit ball, but for $C([a,b],\mathbb R)$, this would only give you constant functions in the unit ball.  But as Matthew Daws says, Philip Brooker's answer covers this and more.