# Is any Banach space a dual space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Is there always a normed vector space $Y$ such that $X$ and $Y^*$ are isometric or isomorphic as topological vector spaces (that is, there exists a linear homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y^*$)?

Comment: No. There is no $Y$ such that $Y^* = L_1[0,1]$. See this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137677/what-is-the-predual-of-l1

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/107706/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210043/

Comment: All these examples need a lot of theory. Do you know if there are elementary arguments?

Comment: The question is subtle. I am not aware of any elementary arguments. You need to use some theory to show that a Banach space is not isometric to a dual space. The argument via Krein-Milman is probably the easiest. Non-isometric Banach spaces can be isomorphic (for example $c_0$ and $c$ are isomorphic but they are not isometric because the unit ball of $c$ has lots of extreme points while the one of $c_0$ doesn't have any) and all $L^p$-spaces with $1 \leq p \lt \infty$ are homeomorphic as topological spaces (even locally Lipschitz), but they are not isomorphic as topological vector spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just sum up the answers given above to refer to my question as answered:

My favorite argument is the one given by commenter [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210043/c-0x-is-not-the-dual-of-a-complete-normed-space) using Krein-Milmann theorem to prove that $C_0(K)$ has no predual space.

A good reference for such questions seems to be *Topics in in Banach Space Theory* by Kalton and Albiac. It is used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107706/the-space-c-omega-mathbbr-has-a-predual) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137677/what-is-the-predual-of-l1) to prove that $C_0(K)$ and $L_1[0,1]$ have no predual space.