# Is every Banach space isometrically isomorphic to the dual of a normed space?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following question:

> Given a Banach space $V$ over the field $\mathbb{K}$, is it true that there is always a normed space $W$ over the field $\mathbb{K}$, such that $V$ and $W'=\mathscr{L}(W,\mathbb{K})$ are isometrically isomorphic (with $\mathbb{K}\in \{\mathbb{R},\ \mathbb{C}\}$)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: No.  Space $c_0$, for example, has no isometric (or even isomorphic) pre-dual.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242034/is-any-banach-space-a-dual-space

Comment: Of interest is the answer to [this post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/148926/quasi-reflexive-spaces-which-are-not-isometric-to-dual-spaces) at MO.