# What is an adjoint operator?

Tags: operator-theory, definition

The following conjeture is stated [here](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~vtroitsky/papers/math/done/complexification/complexification-dated.pdf):

Every adjoint operator has a non-trivial closed invariant subspace.

Reference 11 where adjoint is supposedly defined can be found [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02776031#page-1). But I don't have access to the article.

So what's an "adjoint operator"?

**Edit** It is not "the adjoint of an operator" here because then the conjecture would be equivalent to:

Every operator has a non-trivial closed invariant subspace.

Comment: http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=adjoint+operator

Comment: I know the definition of the adjoint of an operator. But obviously that's not what is meant in the article since a conjecture like that would not make any sense. @JMoravitz

Comment: @student: I don't know a lot of functional analysis, but I'm not sure that your statement is equivalent. Is it the case that every Banach space is isomorphic to the dual of some Banach space? If it isn't, then perhaps not every operator is an adjoint operator, and the theorem is trying to point out a potentially important subtlety.

Comment: @EricStucky [No](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242034/is-any-banach-space-a-dual-space), it seems...

Comment: @student: $*$headdesk$*$ I always forget to do obvious things like *search MSE* when I have questions I don't know the answer to… Thanks for the link :)

Comment: @EricStucky No, I thank you. Your comment was very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Banach space $X$ , the dual space is the Banach space $X^*$ of all bounded linear functionals on $X$. Let $\langle x,f\rangle$ be the value of $f\in X^*$ on $x\in X$. If $T$ is a bounded linear operator on $X$, then its adjoint is a bounded linear operator $T^*$ on $X^*$ which is defined by $\langle x,T^*f\rangle=\langle Tx,f\rangle$ for all $x\in X$ and
$f\in X^*$. There exist Banach space $X$ such that not every bounded linear operator on $X^*$
is the adjoint of an operator on $X$. The question if every operator on $X^*$ which is
an adjoint has a non-trivial closed invariant subspace is stil unsolved. The problem is open even for the infinite dimensional separable complex Hilbert space. It is known, for instance,
that there exists a bounded linear operator $S$ on $l^1$ which does not have non-trivial closed invariant subspaces. Of course, $S$ is not an adjoint operator.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Regarding the concrete example of $\ell^2(\mathbb C)$: What would be an invariant subspace for the right shift operator $Re_n = e_{n+1}$?

Comment: Let $k$ be a positive integer and $M_k$ the closed linear subspace spaned by $e_j$ $(j\geq k)$. Then $M_k$ is a closed invariant subspace for $R$. Closed invariant subspaces of the shift operator have been described by Beurling more than 60 years ago.