# The space of continuous functions as a dual space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, duality-theorems

Let $X$ be some topological Hausdorff space and $C_b(X)$ the space of bounded complex continuous functions on $X$. Is there a Banach space $B$ such that $B^* \simeq C_b (X)$?

I know of a very similar result, namely that $L^\infty (\mu) \simeq L^1 (\mu) ^*$ whenever $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, but I work in a context where continuity is important, so this purely measure-theoretic result is good but not enough.

(Please note that I am not asking about $C_b (X) ^*$, that is a well-known result.)

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107706/the-space-c-omega-mathbbr-has-a-predual) (particularly the comments) says that for compact $X$, that's hardly ever the case. Since for completely regular $X$ we have $C_b(X) = C(\beta X)$, the case of $X$ not completely regular remains. I doubt there's a nice theory about that.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, bounded, thank you. Concerning the question that you reference, how about [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203826/recognizing-schwartz-regular-distributions/212222#212222): *"the space of continuous functions, say on a compact interval, is the dual of the space of measures thereon with the so-called bounded weak star topology"*? That's what I'm trying to get a better view of.

Comment: Do you mean isometric isomorphism or arbitrary isomorphism of Banach spaces?

Comment: I can't really parse that answer, but "bounded weak star topology" indicates a non-normable space. If you drop the normability requirement on the putative predual, then every Banach space $X$ is the dual of $(X',\sigma(X',X))$.

Comment: @AlexM. As for your question in comments it is completely different. In fact the space of continuous functionals on $X^*$ endowed with weak* topology is exactly $X$. It is remains to note that for $X=C(K)$ we have $X^*=M(K)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oh, it may be my mistake, then. Since $C_b (X)$ is viewed as a Banach space, I assumed that it is natural to ask about a Banach predual. I was mistaken, it seems. Does the result that you cite have a well-known name? I'd like to take a look at its details, because in functional analysis these little details can ruin everything.

Comment: @Norbert: Is $M(K)$ the space called $rba(K)$ by Dunford and Schwartz, the space of regular bounded addditive set-functions?

Comment: @AlexM.exactly.